# Unable to expose to Swift an Objective-C class that in turn imports Swift code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, import

I'm mixing `Swift` and `Objective-C` code in my `iOS` project, and I have an `Objective-C` class (let's call it "ObjCClass"), where I use `Swift` classes, so I added this import line to the .h file:

```
#import "MyApp-Swift.h"
```

On the other hand, I need to use that "ObjCClass" class in a certain `Swift` class (let's say "SwiftClass"), so in the "MyApp-Bridging-Header.h" file I'm trying to add:

```
#import "ObjCClass.h"
```

But the compiler gives to me two errors, one in that line in "MyApp-Bridging-Header.h" file, and another in the `#import "MyApp-Swift.h"` of the "ObjCClass.h" file. In the end, the error says `failed to import bridging header`.

I have no problem in exposing to `Swift` my `Objective-C` classes that don't use `Swift` code, am I trying to do something that is not possible? I mean, is it not allowed to use in a `Swift` class an `Objective-C` class that in turn uses another `Swift` class? If this should be possible, how could I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: @obcj class mySwiftClass{...}, rebuild project, have fun (add "@obcj" to class declaration)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all your problem, but you can used Objective-c class in a Swift project like this :

- in "**Build Settings**" search "bridg" then add your "Bridging-Header.h" file (full path relative to your project) in "**Objective-C Bridging Header**"
- your "Bridging-Header.h" file may look like this :

  ```
  #import <yourFramework>
  #import "yourClass.h"
  ```

And you can used Swift class in Objective-c project like this :

- add @class yourClass; in your .h

  ```
  // MyObjcClass.h
  @class yourClass;
  @interface MyObjcClass : NSObject
  - (yourClass *)returnSwiftObject;
  /* ... */
  @end
  ```
- add #import "yourClass-Swift.h"; in yout .m

more info here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Answer (score 0):

This problem is the same as if you tried to #import the header file of ClassA in ClassB.h, while importing the header file of ClassB in ClassA.h—you can't have circular imports.

The solution is the same here as if it was a pure Objective-C project. Move your `#import "MyApp-Swift.h"`to the top of your ObjCClass.m, instead of in the .h. Meanwhile, if you need to reference any Swift classes in the header of ObjCClass, not just in the .m, then include those classes with `@class` declarations in ObjCClass.h.

If you do the above, your compiler problems will go away. You won't need to change anything in your bridging header.